# Mysql query to establish group dates on daily records

Tags: mysql, date

i have a table with day_date and price each record is displayed as below:

```
Day_date   Price
2012-05-20 500
2012-05-21 500
2012-05-22 500
2012-05-23 600
2012-05-24 600
2012-05-25 500
2012-05-26 500
2012-05-27 700
2012-05-28 700
```

what i want to do is display as follow:

```
season 2012-05-20 to 2012-05-22 price 500
season 2012-05-23 to 2012-05-24 price 600
season 2012-05-25 to 2012-05-26 price 500
season 2012-05-27 to 2012-05-28 price 700
```

I am trying to do this using the following query below:

```
SELECT min(day_add) as start_date, max(day_add) as end_date, price 
FROM table GROUP BY price
```

With this query i get the following result:

```
2012-05-20  2012-05-26  500
2012-05-23  2012-05-24  600
2012-05-27  2012-05-28  700
```

as you see compared what i want to do is that the first record with `price=500` should be from 20 to 22 of May 2012 and then on 3rd place should come 25 to 26 may wich the `price=500`.

Since i am grouping by price it's cutting the season from 25 to 26 may 2012.

Is it possible to do `SELECT` to get the results as i want?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the query itself but with the data, as there is no value to group by. All you have to do is to create that new value.

You can do that this way:

```
select min(day_date) minDate, max(day_date) maxDate, price from (
  select day_date, @row := @row + (@price != price) grp, @price := price price
  from t, (select @row := 0, @price := '') init
  order by day_date
) final
group by final.grp, price
```

Here you have the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fec74/1) to play with.

Comment: Hello Mosty, thank you for your reply i did try and works fine i was just trying to understand how the syntax you used works and if i have another column called allotment where all the values are =2 how would i also group it?

Comment: @user1361389 Hey! Just remove the outer select and the group by. You'll see the trick I'm doing there. If you already have some kind of column that has a different value per group, then you can do with it. If you don't you'll have to create it this way.